# Cheapest hosting company that would give me lots of IPs

Tags: ip, vps

Any recommendation on hosting company that would give me lots of ips(**/22,/23,/24,/25,/26**) with a dedicated server and chopped it up into vps for me?

Comment: What do you want it for?

Comment: Do you want that single dedicated server chopped into the thousand VPSes that would be needed to use all of those IPs?

Comment: MarkM, yes, I don't need thousands, just hundreds

Answer (score 3):

Any hosting company should be willing to give you a /22 of space, **as long as you can justify it**.  I'll place a smallish wager that you won't be able to justify that much space, though.

Comment: please read my post carefully, any range from /26 up to /22... not /22 specifically..

Comment: Please feel free to substitute /22 for any other range you like; my answer is all purpose like that.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many public IPs you want you'll have to justify to the CoLo, who forwards the justification on to ICANN that you need that many IPs.  That's anywhere from 5 IPs on up.

Answer (score 0):

A /22 is *a lot* of IPv4 space.  You're not going to find many/any that will give you that large an allocation.  You'll probably have to go to your local internet registry (like APNIC) and justify/order your own range.  From there you can try and find a host that will advertise it for you.

Comment: it depends on if he wants the /22 in private or public IPs

Comment: So *that's* what all those hosting providers offering a "free /8 of IP space" were up to...

Answer (score 0):

/22 is a gigantic amount of IP space.  I find it hard to believe that anyone who could justify that much IP space from a hosting company would ask where to go on ServerFault.  But, if you can justify and pay for it, just find a host that has it for you and they should be willing to give it.

The hosting company I work for (Rackspace) does /26 blocks all the time for clients.

As far as the server, many hosts, including the one I work for, support virtualization for their clients...but I'm not sure you'd want to host a /22 worth of VMs on a single dedicated box.  You're talking about 1022 hosts or so.  For a /26, it's a bit more reasonable.  Either way, our virtualization team supports all kind of client configs, and I'm sure most other higher-end hosting companies do as well.

If you want to be raising huge numbers of VPSes, you might want to look in to a product like Rackspace Cloud Servers or Amazon EC-2.

Comment: I believe it's 1024.... not 65,534....

Comment: You're right I had a brain fart...1022 hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Our current hoster [NTT Europe Online](http://ntt.eu) gave us /24 public range without asking for any justification. We had to chop it up to VPSes ourselves though because they don't know anything except vmware, and they are not cheap, their managed hosting costs 4 times more that Rackspace's.

We did not really need that many IPs, its just how they do things, all IPs are public. I can not imagine any legitimate need for that many IPs except you are planning to be an ISP yourself, but in that case it is better to get a real colo and arrange the links and ranges yourself, otherwise I don't believe you can be competitive enough to survive.